# Randomly merging two linked lists

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, shuffle

I'll start by saying I've looked for and tried several different solutions without luck.  I've been working on this for far too long, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The assignment is to shuffle a linked list representing a deck of cards.  I was given all method declarations and was told I'm only allowed to use recursion.  I've gone about this in every possible way I can think of without any luck.

Basically the strategy we were told to use is to split the linked list in 2, shuffle both lists (by recursively calling the shuffle method), then merge the shuffled lists back together.

Some stuff you may need to know:

- LLN = Linked List Node
- len = the length of the "this" list
- b = the list to merge "this" with
- blen = the length of the "b" list

This code returns an empty list, and I can't see why (obviously).  LLN->shuffle() should return the head of the shuffled list.  Right now it's returning an empty list.

```
LLN * LLN::merge(int len, LLN *b, int blen) {
    //cout << "len: " << len << ", blen: " << blen << endl;

    if (len == 0) return b;
    if (blen == 0) return this;

    int r = rand() % (len + blen) + 1; // between 1 and (len + blen)

    if (r <= len) {
        if (next)
            next = next->merge(len - 1, b, blen);
        else
            next = b;

        return this;
    } else {
        if (b->getnext())
            b->setnext(b->getnext()->merge(blen - 1, this, len));
        else
            b->setnext(this);

        return b;
    }
}

LLN *LLN::shuffle(int len) {
    if (len == 1)
        return this;

    LLN *tmp = split();

    int thisLength = (len + 1) / 2; // for an odd numbered length, "this" list is 1 node larger
    int tmpLength = len / 2;

    shuffle(thisLength);
    tmp = tmp->shuffle(tmpLength);

    return merge(thisLength, tmp, tmpLength);
}
```

This is how the method is invoked.

```
void LL::shuffle() {
    if (head != NULL)
        head = head->shuffle(size);
}
```

The LL (Linked List) object is initialized with the standard 52 cards (each card being a node).

If you need anything else, please let me know.

Thanks very much!

Comment: But what is the problem? Give an example of what you want and what you get?

Comment: I want it to shuffle the list.  What I get is an empty list. LLN->shuffle() should return the head of the shuffled list (hence why in LL->shuffle() the head node gets reset).

Comment: What is doing the `split()` method?

Comment: Called in LLN->shuffle().  Basically the 52 card list gets split in 2, then those two lists get split in 2 and so on until there's only one node in the list.  When both lists have been split down to a single node, LLN->merge is called until we're back to a 52 node list.

Comment: Without sending parameters to `split()` I think it's hard to make sure the method is doing it's job as supposed. I think the best way is `shuffle()` method to receive a list and let `split()` to work on that portion of the list, or if you don't want to split the list in sub-lists, send the appropriate parameters that identify a portion of the list, e.g. `shuffle(len, start, end)`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to change method arguments.  I was given the definitions and that's what I have to work with.  I did fix my problem, though (see below). :)  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem with help from my prof.  Turns out my error was in the base case for my split() method.  With that fixed everything works fine.  I also applied Charlie's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
shuffle(thisLength);
tmp = tmp->shuffle(tmpLength);

return merge(thisLength, tmp, tmpLength);
```

Here *shuffle(thisLength)*'s return value may **not** is *this*, so we should do like this

```
first = shuffle(thisLength);
tmp = tmp->shuffle(tmpLength);

return first->merge(thisLength, tmp, tmpLength);
```

Comment: I've tried that before (and just did again), and it still returns an empty list.